# How to make the UI like this? in oc language

Tags: ios

Every part of the UI is irregular, i think the UI is attractive and i really want to know how to make it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't do this kind of stuff directly in `Storyboard`.**

To achieve this type  of functionality , You have to manage all `UIView` or `UIButton` Programmatically.

Please do as below step.

1) Please download [demo Project](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQIrregularView) and  Drag `IQIrregularView.h` and `IQIrregularView.m` file in project

2) How to use this library You can shown in [demo](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQIrregularView).

Happy coding...

**NOTE: This library just draw a `UIBezierPath` in `UIView` and also handle the Tap events.**